# Figure out if web page is the only tab in a window?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there a way to figure out if the tab your web page is running in, is the only tab in the window or not? I've been looking on google for about 20 mins now and couldnt find anything even similar to this. I'd prefer to do it without any add-ons/plugins/etc. but if i have to use a plugin the only one I can use is Java.

Comment: There sure are a lot of nosy developers out there, how many tabs, which tab, only tab? This tab, that tab, my tab, your tab, can't close that tab, not before his tab, but move his tab, you're logging in again over in that tab. Geez Louis... `:D`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's absolutely no way to do this, in any browser. Which other tabs are open or not is outside your web page's control.

Comment: This is correct, what you ask can't be done due to security restrictions. The obvious question is: why do you need to do this? Is there no other way to accomplish what you're looking for? If this is for some sort of security purpose, then a browser environment really isn't ideal.

Comment: this is actually for a home page app that displays different information depending on if its the only tab running or if there are others

Comment: @leaf forget it, it's not possible. Maybe from a browser add-on... *maybe*, in some browsers, and you would have to do major programming work for each browser